# T SQL Select only first record for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have created a view which includes specific tables from a SQL database and I can select all the samples from all the tables from a date range sucessfully. Here is a portion of the view design:

```
SELECT 'PLANT FLOW1' AS 'Tag', ts AS 'Timestamp', value AS 'Data'
FROM dbo.UASTP_150000_TL63
UNION
SELECT 'PLANT FLOW2' AS 'Tag', ts AS 'Timestamp', value AS 'Data'
FROM dbo.UASTP_150000_TL10
UNION
SELECT 'INFLUENT FLOW' AS 'Tag', ts AS 'Timestamp', value AS 'Data'
FROM dbo.UASTP_150000_TL1
UNION
SELECT 'EFFLUENT FLOW' AS 'Tag', ts AS 'Timestamp', value AS 'Data'
FROM dbo.UASTP_150000_TL2
UNION
```

I need to select only the first reading each day from each table. I found some sample code and tried to incorporate it, but it doesn't work.

Bad T-SQL code:

```
SELECT TOP (100) percent [Tag]
      ,[Timestamp]
      ,[Data]
  FROM [enteliwebDB].[dbo].[WIMS_View]
  where Timestamp >= DATEADD(day, -30, getdate())
  and Timestamp <= getdate()
  and where Tag in(
    SELECT min(Timestamp)
  )
  order by Tag, Timestamp
```

When I just run a query for a data range this is the kind of output I get which includes all samples for every table:

```
Tag Timestamp   Data
9012 TURBIDITY METER TREND  2019-03-10 11:41:14.0680000 5.1552605629
9012 TURBIDITY METER TREND  2019-03-10 11:51:14.0630000 5.14915704727
9012 TURBIDITY METER TREND  2019-03-10 12:01:14.0600000 5.12321662903
9012 TURBIDITY METER TREND  2019-03-10 12:11:14.0560000 5.16212701797
9012 TURBIDITY METER TREND  2019-03-10 12:21:14.0540000 5.12703132629
9012 TURBIDITY METER TREND  2019-03-10 12:31:14.0500000 5.13313484192
9012 TURBIDITY METER TREND  2019-03-10 12:41:14.0470000 5.17814922333
9012 TURBIDITY METER TREND  2019-03-10 12:51:14.0410000 5.14000177383
```

Can you tell me how to pull just the first sample each day from each table?

Answer (score 6):

Try this query. It uses subquery with `ROW_NUMBER` to determine first record per table ordered by timestamp:

```
SELECT [Tag],
       [Timestamp],
       [Data]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ts DESC PARTITION BY Tag) [rn],
           [Tag],
           [Timestamp],
           [Data]
    FROM MyView
) [a] WHERE [rn] = 1;
```

Comment: I've tried the following but I get 2 syntax errors on line 6 by "SELECT" and "BY":                                                SELECT [Tag],
       [Timestamp],
       [Data]
FROM (
 [enteliwebDB].[dbo].[WIMS_View]
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ts DESC PARTITION BY Tag) [rn],
           [Tag],
           [Timestamp],
           [Data]
    FROM WIMS_View
) [a] WHERE [rn] = 1;

Comment: Try reordering the ORDER BY clause to (PARTITION BY Tag ORDER BY ts DESC)

Answer (score 5):

We can try using a CTE with your computed column to keep track of the table source:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 'PLANT FLOW1' AS tag, ts AS Timestamp, [value] AS data
    FROM dbo.UASTP_150000_TL63
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'PLANT FLOW2', ts, [value] FROM dbo.UASTP_150000_TL10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'INFLUENT FLOW', ts, [value] FROM dbo.UASTP_150000_TL1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'EFFLUENT FLOW', ts, [value] FROM dbo.UASTP_150000_TL2
)

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    tag,
    ts,
    [value]
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tag, CONVERT(date, ts) ORDER BY ts);
```

Note carefully that the partition here is by `tag` (i.e. per table) *and* by the *date* of each record.  Hence, we use `CONVERT` to obtain the date of each timestamp.  We avoid a subquery altogether by using a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` trick where `ROW_NUMBER` appears in the `ORDER BY` clause.